# Akka actors vs nodejs worker thread. Why (if) actors are better?

Tags: node.js, scala, actor

Not long ago I was on job interview and interviewer asked me a question: "Why akka actors are better than nodejs worker thread?" 
I didn't answer this question, because I don't know how to answer this. 
I understand that it is not really stackoverflow question, but still. How would you answer? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Guessing a bit, the question seems to be asked from the side of someone who personally prefers akka actors.

I haven't used nodejs workers but I imagine that are similar to actors in that they are basically an event loop reacting to a queue of messages (or inbox).

Actors have other features in regard to error handling in that:

1. They form hierarchies where an actor has children and a parent.
2. This hierarchies form error handling domains.

So in this case, if there is an error, an actor can decide what to do or send it up. The parent then can decide whether to restart the actor that failed or all the actors

Also, actors have separated identity from state, so you can refer to an actor without worrying about its state. An actor can be killed or restarted but all the owners of a reference can still send messages to that address without caring about the current state of that particular actor.

I'm only answering without the whole picture, so I'm expecting to be corrected or called out for omissions.